# microphone input is not working after upgrade

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers

I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 system with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and now my external microphone doesn't work anymore (it was working yesterday and its works now on other devices) and I need it for work.

When I open the sound settings, input tab, I don't see the input signal.

My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad t400

A few commands:

`sudo aplay -l`

```
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], périphérique 0: CX20561 Analog [CX20561 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], périphérique 1: CX20561 Digital [CX20561 Digital]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

`pactl list short sinks`

```
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfc020000 irq 49
29 [ThinkPadEC     ]: ThinkPad EC - ThinkPad Console Audio Control
                      ThinkPad Console Audio Control at EC reg 0x30, fw 7VHT16WW-1.06
```